# How to switch to the tab where I'm working on a particular file?

Tags: vim, tabs

How can I switch to the tab where I'm working on a particular file, when I know its filename, but not its tab number?

Suppose I have lots of open tabs in Vim, say 20, and I need to move to the particular tab where I'm working on file `foo`. The thing is, I don't know the tab number. So `{number}gt` will not do. And I'm lazy to have to switch among 19 tabs until I find it.

I'm looking for something like `gt foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this option:

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
```

in your `~/.vimrc` you can do `:sb foo` to go to buffer `foo` wherever it is displayed.

See `:help :sb` and `:help switchbuf`.

*However…*

Vim's tab pages are not at all like tabs in other editors: you can't have a 1:1 relationship between a tab page and a file/buffer or even between a window and a file/buffer. Tab pages are more like ad-hoc workspaces and windows are viewports.

Buffers are Vim's real file proxies (and more) so, my advice is to drop tab pages and use straight buffers instead.

Comment: Didn't know I could work with buffers directly. If I understand correctly, it's okay to keep using tab pages provided I move to a (window in a) tab page through its buffer number or name, instead of its tab number, right? Or is there any reason to drop tab pages altogether?

Comment: No, you should use tab pages like the workspaces they are actually designed as and windows as the viewports they are actually designed as. That means that you can't build a tab/windows-centric workflow that's as fluid as a buffer-centric workflow and thus, that you should use buffers mainly.